# Cannot convert array to object[][]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am currently working with two arrays(They are not same size, dont have the same order or format), my goal is to get information from one array and input into another array to eventually use the setRange() method to input the data from one spreadsheet to the other. I have the following code so far:

```
fileName = currentFile.getName()
fileSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(currentFile).getSheetByName(fileName);
var SAFRange = fileSheet.getRange("A1:K29").getValues(); // values from the SAF
var SKU = 0 //used as a counter to see how many SKUs are in a SAF.
for (i = 15; i <= 27; i++) { // first loop just checks how many information is needed
    if (!(SAFRange[i][0] == "")) {
        SKU++; // increase counter, used to determined how many rows are 
        //needed
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
//recap is the destination spreadsheet defined before
//recLRow is the last row of recap
//The array below is an array with al blank values  
var newInfo = recap.getRange("A" + (recLRow + 1).toString() + ":R" + (recLRow + SKU+1).toString()).getValues(); // gets  the values of the range that the information will be posted. in this case all "" -- Blanks
Logger.log(newInfo)
var rowIndex = 0 //row index for the second array
for (i = 15; i <= (15 + SKU); i++) { // This Loop gets the information from the SAF and puts in the appropiate Range
    newInfo.splice([rowIndex][4], 1, SAFRange[i][0]); //TBH im not sure how
    Logger.log(newInfo);                              //Splice works, 
    rowIndex++;                                       //Error might me here
}
//Below is  where the program flags an error.
recap.getRange("A" + (recLRow + 1).toString() + ":R" + (recLRow + SKU+1).toString()).setValues(newInfo);
```

I have this logs from before and after the splice:

```
Before: [[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]]
After: [00029HB00, [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]]
```

so i know im doing it wrong. I want to inset the information within the first array, not replace the whole thing

> Error:Cannot convert array to object[][]

Comment: You need to put newInfo into an array or every element within it to have a 2d grid

Comment: Im sorry I dont really understand what you mean. I dont have a computer science background(Except one programming course) i work in Finance. Would you mind showing me some code?

Comment: You ought to know that arrays in Google sheets especially when using getRange are 2D arrays. I think your problem is coming from that. And, go learn some programming concepts too.

Comment: Ok after some reading know i get the concept of 2D arrays, and by looking at my logs i know that the problem is that after i splice. Trying to replace a value in a specified row(a cell to be more specific). Can anybody show me how to do that? and yes noogui i am for sure learning more concepts.